# C++ Inline assembly errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to work with inline assembly but I'm receiving errors..

Here's a part of the code:

```
char * buffer = new char[10];
__asm {
    mov ecx,&buffer
    mov edx,07
}
```

And the errors;

> Error 1   error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second
>   operand'; found 'AND'

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Visual C++ is a distant memory for me, but how about `lea ecx, buffer` ?

Comment: You defined buffer as a pointer, why are you passing a double pointer to ecx?  is that correct?

Comment: `&` is AND operator in assembly language. It looks like you're using C++ in an _asm block, which tends not to work out well. It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Are you try to load the value of `buffer` into a register? Or are you trying to load the address of the `buffer` variable?

Comment: I'm trying to load the address

Comment: Which address are you trying to load? The address of the 10 characters you just created? Or the address of the `buffer` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

*1. If you are trying to load the addres of the allocated `char` array into `ecx`*

The value of `buffer` already is the address you need for `ecx`. Its something like `0x004F5A42` (just for example) which is the address of the `char` array in memory, so no reason for having `&` attached to `buffer` in your asm code. `&buffer` would be the address of the `buffer` pointer itself which  in memory may be megabytes away from the `char` array.

*2. If you are trying to load the addres of `buffer` into `ecx`*

You should probably try this:

```
char * buffer = new char[10];
char ** buffer_ptr = &buffer;
__asm {
    mov ecx,buffer_ptr
    mov edx,07
}
```

The reason for this workaround is that, as it appears, the role of `&` is solely reserved to the AND operator. The following quote is taken from [x86 Assembly Language Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf)

> **Operators**
>
> The assembler supports the following operators for use in expressions.
>
> ...
>
> &    Bitwise logical AND

and thereafter `&` is never mentioned in the manual.

Comment: "*`&buffer` would be the address of the `buffer` pointer itself*" Which is what the OP said in comments that they want. ;-]